# Using TouchImageView for display GPS location

Tags: android, imageview

I am using TouchImageView https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView to show image map. On that map I need to display some dot (ImageView). I have 2 classes:

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView
public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity
```

How can i track the position of my image in TouchImageView and return it to TouchImageViewActivity for setting dot position? Should I add listener or some other idea, because i cannot set new imageView position in the TouchImageView class.

TouchImageViewActivity:
(The dot now is static)

```
public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_touch_image_view);



    TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.g_map2048);
    img.setMaxZoom(6f);


    ImageView imDot = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImDot3);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(150, 150, 0, 0);
    imDot.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a fork of that repository. I Added pins (markers) over the zoomable image, which can be dragged. And you can get the position of the pin (ImageView) pressing a button.
https://github.com/Mariovc/TouchImageView